# PHP Concatenation assignment

Tags: php

Basic question using .= (concatenation assignment) in a loop.

This code produces this PHP error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: html

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    $html .= "<h1>Stuff</h1>";
}
```

If I add an `$html = "";` before the loop the error is corrected. Is this the best way to correct this, or am I missing something?

How do I use the `.=` operator within a loop, and any direction to tutorials to better understand this would be appreciated?

Comment: You don't miss anything. You corrected the code correctly.

Comment: you need to add the `$html = ""` outside of the loop else you are attempting to concatenate null with a string which wont work. Thus your correction of adding `$html = ""` before the loop is correct.

Comment: @Matt Technically, it _will_ work. It generates a notice, but PHP will treat the undefined variable as `""` and do the concatenation anyway.

Comment: Does the answer fixes notice you were receiving? If yes could you accept answer, else please provide more details / questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html .= "something";
```

**Above code is translated to:**

```
$html = $html."something";
```

so you are trying to concatenate "something" to $html and since $html is not initialised thus you getting the error.

So please initialise the $html above loop and that's the correct way.